# Checking terms of a sequence against values in array

Tags: java, arrays, sequences

Why isn't this working? I am trying to check terms of the sequence a_j)=38^j +31 against values in the array. I am saying trying to get that if the specific term in the sequence is not divisible by any of these values in the array then print it.

```
    public class SmallestPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long m =0;

        int [] b = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

        for(int j=0;j<6;j++) { 

            m = (long) Math.pow(38,j) + 31;

            if(m % b[j] !=0) {

                System.out.println(m);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It prints,1475
54903
2085167
79235199, which is clearly not right since we have numbers divisible by 3,5 which should not have printed based on b[1],b[3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looping only once.

For example when `j = 2` you only check if 1475 is divisible by `b[2]` which happens to be 4 and 1475 is not divisible by 4 thus printing your value.

You'll need to use a nested loop to achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is a bit of code to help out:

```
private static void smallestPrime() {
long m = 0;

int[] b = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

for (int j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {

    m = (long) Math.pow(38, j) + 31;
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (m % b[i] == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
    }
    System.out.println(m + " : " + prime);
}
}
```